# How to share access tokens using AccountManager among different signed apps?

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm implementing **SSO** (Single Sign-On) feature between different apps signed with different keys.

To accomplish this I'm using the `AccountManager` api, creating an account and saving an access token on it for retrieval by other apps other than the one who created the account at first place.

The caveat is that, as a security constraint, only apps whose **uid** are the same as the authenticator's **uid** or the ones that are signed with the same keystore can access the private data stored there.

Is it possible to save access tokens in a way that they can be shared on apps with different signatures, maybe with different token types? Or any way to whitelist some apps to access the account?

Comment: how you will control/ or decide which apps are white-listed ?

Comment: @RahulTiwari actually I'm not concerned with that at first. I just want to make the sharing work. :)

Answer (score 1):

one way of sharing token can be via content provider.

one can have check on calling application using `Binder.getCallingUid`.

calling uid can further be used to identify calling package name if necessary.

source: I have personally used this in an MDM solution

Comment: I thought about using a content provider to share a token stored at sharedpreferences or sqlite, but I don't think the solution suits very well since I would like that given token to be centralized for a group of apps even if the one who created the account first is uninstalled. 
How do you used the uid you got using your solution?

Comment: in my case token was with system admin app. and anyways as soon as you will uninstall all apps from signature group to which account manager belong, account will automatically get deleted. so you can not use it in the way you are thinking.

Comment: Uninstalling all the apps and remove the account is not a problem. I don't want that uninstalling the app that created the account to delete the account from the system.

Comment: you mean to say your apps will share same signature?

Comment: The opposite. All of them with different signatures.

Comment: then as soon as you will uninstall the one who created the account the account will be deleted. I can't think of a secure storage which remains there or is being shared between apps with different signature. that's an obvious security threat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91129/discussion-between-rahul-tiwari-and-kaneda).

Comment: @kaneda How did you solve this in the end? I have a similar use case.

Comment: @RahulTiwari I kind of have some similar issue I reckon. Can you please look into it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120775/android-account-manager-not-detecting-package-type

Comment: @RahulTiwari were you able to find a solution for the problem statement. I am also caught up in a similar situation where I want the apps signed with different signature to access the same account manager