# Android Account Manager not detecting package type

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have an Android SDK and I want to use Account Manager to centralise my accounts. The SDK will create an account if the device is registered the first time, if not, it will reuse the same account from the Account Manager.

*Issue*: If I install 2 apps from my own PC. I can see that the first account is created and is reused by the second app. However, when I install 2 apps from different PC's. The second app is not able to detect the account created by the first app and throws an error
`java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10413 cannot explicitly add accounts of type: com.example`

In the second scenario, I can see other accounts on the device like Google, Skype, and Whatsapp which are ofcourse not installed from my PC and have a different signature as well then how come these package names and types are visible and not mine?

**Resolved:** *I was using read contact permission but was missing write contact permission.*

Comment: You need to use the same debug signature on every machine checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178735/sharing-android-debug-certificate-across-different-developer-machines-in-android, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924901/using-the-same-debug-keystore-on-multiple-computers or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365481/share-debug-keystore for answers on how to do that

Comment: Thanks @TaranmeetSingh, I think this would work fine for the company's internal usage. However, I am planning to integrate the SDK through Jitpack with multiple pre-existing applications. Any idea if it can be added with in AAR or something so the other device can detect it in some manner?

Answer (score 2):

At a time only one app can register for adding account of a type.

The app that add accounts and the app that need account need to be of same signature. when you are trying from same PC, same debug signature is getting applied so you are able to access.

Or set visibility for packages of other apps that want to access the account while adding the accounts or after adding the account. see method - AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly or setAccountVisibility

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to add the setAccountVisibilty. However, I noticed that I can only set it to my application package/project. The moment I try to add other packages (From 2nd PC), the code returns false for being unable to set the visibility. The android document states that they need to have the same signature but how can I possibly have the same signature will all the company/partner's applications as I have an SDK which is integrating into other applications. @TaranmeetSingh suggested a way to share debug signature. However, I think it's only feasible for internal work only.